# What happens in Android: Netrunner when your deck runs out and you need to draw a card?

Tags: android-netrunner

Do you lose as in magic? Do you reshuffle your discard pile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the Corporation player attempts to draw from his empty R&D deck, he loses the game. From the [rules PDF](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/android-netrunner-core-rules.pdf), page 3:

> ...the Runner wins if the Corporation must draw a card from his empty draw deck

The Runner simply loses the ability to draw more cards if his Stack is empty, but it's not a game-ender. You don't reshuffle.